# Why is Font Awesome not working in JSbin?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, jsbin

I'm new to this so forgive me if the answer is obvious, but I can't figure out why my font awesome symbol is not appearing when I use JSbin. Any advice?

The html is in  and in the my css for font awesome in particular is at the very bottom.

https://jsbin.com/wagaji/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is something wrong with the files you are referring to for fontawesome.

Here is another file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Here is a working [demo](https://jsbin.com/yipefocope/edit?html,css,js)

I also realized, you are referring to version `4.4.0` of the file, and the latest one on [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome#) is `4.5.0` . I'm not sure if that made a difference, but it works with that as well.[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/zeyaguqadu/edit?html,css,js)

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot! I'll have to learn more about referring to files.

Comment: It also might have to do with the version of the file you were referring to.You were using version 4.4.0, the latest one on cdnjs is 4.5.I'll just add that to the answer